# how is it possible to get gccgo produce vectorized code?

Tags: go, vectorization, gccgo

I'm trying to convince gccgo without success to vectorize the following snippet:

```
package foo

func Sum(v []float32) float32 {
    var sum float32 = 0
    for _, x := range v {
        sum += x
    }
    return sum
}
```

I'm verifying the assembly generated by:

```
$ gccgo -O3 -ffast-math -march=native -S test.go
```

gccgo version is:

```
$ gccgo --version
gccgo (Ubuntu 4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1) 4.9.0 20140405 (experimental) [trunk revision 209157]
```

Isn't gccgo supposed to be able to vectorize this code? the equivalent C code 
with the same gcc options is perfectly vectorized with AVX instructions...

**UPDATE**

here you have the corresponding C example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

float sum(float *v, size_t n) {
    size_t i;
    float sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += v[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

compile with:

```
$ gcc -O3 -ffast-math -march=native -S test.c
```

Comment: could you provide the C example as well?

Comment: @konsolebox, no updates. On the other hand, at the present state, gccgo is not competitive with respect to go compiler since it doesn't implement escape analysis...

Comment: Range loops make a copies of values they are ranging over. This would be like if the C for loop was copying into a temp variable (val = v[i]; sume += val) before adding to sum. I would recommend trying to use the same style for loop in your Go code as your C code, and see if that change results in vectorization taking place.

Comment: @voidlogic, I've just tried all possible options for the for loop. No vectorization whatsoever. Looking at the assembly I think it has to do with bounds checking. I'm wondering if there's a way to disable it with gccgo ...

Comment: You can turn off bounds checking: go build -gcflags=-B

Answer (score 1):

Why not just build the .so or .a with gcc and call the c function from go?